# We need to have an easily reachable link for the type of questions that we don't answer

Tags: feature-request

This is the nth time somebody is asking "is this legal", "I need to know whether this is legal", etc.

I suggest that you at least add a line to the "Off-Topic Questions" paragraph that explicitly states that we don't answer "is it legal", "I need to know whether this is legal", etc. Here is the link to the age that I'd like to see updated: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

If anyone is asking questions, the list of off-topic questions should be the first thing they see. I'd like to see "we are not a legal services agency", "we don't offer medical advice", etc. Questions such as "To whom should I redirect my question?" should be perhaps allowable. This is the nth-time that I have written "If in the US, redirect your question to your state's Department of Labor".

Comment: We can answer some legal questions.  The type of questions we can asnwer are those that are factual.  What is the law, what are the regulations, what is expected.  What we cant are advice questions, what shoudl I do, is this illegal, can I sue, can I be sued...

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings - "Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click here. " You are contradicting the TOS of this site. Try again.

Comment: Legal advice... not legal information.  There is a huge difference

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings - As I said, you are contradicting the TOS of this site. There are 180 countries on this Earth, and you claim that we can give legal information on them? The question "is this legal?" amounts to soliciting legal advice.

Comment: "Yes is this legal" is advice.  "What is the law" is asking for factual information.  Just because you do not know the answer does not make it off topic.

Comment: I actually don't think that we can edit that page. We can edit [this page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but I don't see the ability to modify the text on that one?

Comment: @enderland - editing the page you linked to explicitly add "we don't offer legal advice" to the list of Off-Topic Questions might help. Up to at least one third of the questions we end up closing ask for legal advice,

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan just FYI, once you have 10k rep you can look at the actual close vote statistics - if you go to Review --> Tools --> Close -->  Question Close Stats (or just click [this link](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats)). Only about 15% of questions get closed with that reason, which also is in the "company specific" criteria.

Comment: @enderland - thanks for the info. I was reacting to the latest surge of "is it legal" questions. Admittedly not cumulative statistics.

Comment: [Programmers Meta](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) has a similar question - [Why was my question closed or down voted](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6483/64132).  Perhaps something similar would be a good idea here?

Answer (score 2):

### I agree.  It is an easy edit to make, and it may serve to prevent some future problems.

I think we will still see a lot of off topic questions, but for those users who ***are*** making a good faith effort, it will give them an additional tool to determine if their question is a good fit.

There is certainly no downside to making the edit.  Worst case scenario it doesn't have the desired affect and we're talking about the problem again soon.