# (REOPENED) Incorrect duplicate "How to quit right after an apprenticeship"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

Hi this Q about how to quit after an apprenticeship is not a duplicate as the relationship between the employer (master) is quite different to a normal employer employee one.

Additionally it is very country dependant and in some instances still has hold overs from their medieval roots

[How to quit right after an apprenticeship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99349/how-to-quit-right-after-an-apprenticeship)

Comment: Neuromancer, would you mind marking one of the answers as correct? The [Community bot](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/how-does-a-question-get-bumped-to-the-homepage) has bumped this multiple times now, even though it's been completed.

Comment: @DavidK another time now :)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* This question has been reopened.

---

I agree with it not being a duplicate of those questions, voting to open. Let's see what others think about it.

However do notice that even though the post is probably not a dupe of the linked questions you may still find *useful* the answers given in those. Specially the first one, one suggesting *how* to tell your boss you quit, as the closed post seems to be asking that in a way (still, quitting an apprenticeship is not the same as quitting other forms of jobs, so different answers may apply).

The other marked dupe (quit when critical staff member) is more clearly quite different to the closed question and I consider it is not really a dupe of the post.

If you mention that this is "country specific" then propper tagging should be included in the question so answerers can address that situation. Probably the post could use some extra <s>love</s> edits to focus more on important details like the fact there is *no clauses in contract requiring to stay working* after the degree, and the *one month notice* that is in the OP's contract (I'll try the edits tomorrow if no one else has taken a shot on them).

Comment: As of now it has already 3 reopen votes, missing other 2

Comment: It is now reopened

Answer (score 1):

This question has been reopened.