# Kind reminder when posting reopen requests

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to kindly remind you that **we have a [reopen-request](/questions/tagged/reopen-request) tag**, that is intended to use along meta posts that ask for... well... a reopen request.

Please, let's stick to using the tag when it is intended, as *omitting it makes it difficult to browse for reopen requests posts* to give them the attention they deserve, not to mention that it makes our site *less organized and tidy*.

It also makes it impossible for users that watch the tag to find new posts about those requests.

I have no problem in editing the tags when I see they are lacking, but it would be best to include it since the beginning.

Comment: Thnx, didn’t realize it existed.

Answer (score 8):

Another reminder when posting a reopen request, please make sure to accept an answer once it is completed. This is the preferred way of indicating that a question has been reopened, not just [marking it as (Done)](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5724/what-is-with-the-done-in-titles-here).

The reason to accept an answer is that every so often the [Community Bot will bump the question to the homepage](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/how-does-a-question-get-bumped-to-the-homepage). This can be pretty annoying if a bunch of already-completed reopen requests suddenly appear on the top of the Meta page.

Comment: Agree. To complement what you say, it is also good idea to post an answer saying that the post is now reopened, when one sees that a post is (Done) but lacks answer, and so it can be accepted and avoid the bumping

Comment: @DarkCygnus Though according to Monica in the linked answer, it sounds like if a question doesn't have any answers then it won't get bumped. So maybe if no one has said anything, we change the title only?

Comment: hmmm... well, perhaps then we can leave the post unanswered... although, as a Q & **A** site, it seems against the main purpose of the site (to gather high quality Q and As) to not answer... but in practical terms I guess we could go for either option.

Comment: Alternatively, the answer just needs a positive score to prevent the question being bumped, so if the question in the meta question has been reopened, and if there's an unaccepted answer, just upvote it :)

Comment: I prefer the 'Done', makes it more visible that it was specifically a reopen request and saves me clicking on it to see what it's about.